# Rails, forms. jquery, actions with classes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have root_path (index method), like this:

```
<% link_to day, root_path(:day => day) %>
```

I want click to this link, and afterclick this link change color. How can I make it? How can I use jquery?

Answer (score 2):

you would do this using css not jquery. just set your css tags for links (`a` is a link, as in `<a href="">`

```
a {
  color: UNCLICKED COLOR;
}

a:visited {
  color: CLICKED COLOR;
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it should be noted that the browser remembers whether a link has been clicked for some time, and also that it relies on the URL in the "href" attribute to keep track.

Comment: Good point to keep in mind if your URL's are changing and/or this link highlighting is a more essential feature (ie linked to something else)